# convert string to json object using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string which is from an ajax response.

```
"<option value="1000133925">Abhishek</option>
<option value="1000182033">FRESH</option>
<option value="1000390154">Testing</option>"
```

I have another string of the same above format, i need to compare both the strings and remove duplicate values in the second string and then append the remaining options to select.

I failed in creating a json object from the above string which will map like { '1000133925' : 'Abhishek', '1000182033' : 'FRESH'}. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please show us your code first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you insist on using regex, when you can do it using `jQuery` like:

```
var options = '<option value="1000133925">Abhishek</option><option value="1000182033">FRESH</option><option value="1000390154">Testing</option>';
$(options).filter(function(index, el){
    //put here your condition for instance I have filtered odd values
    return (!isNaN(parseInt(this.value)) && parseInt(this.value)%2);
}).appendTo("#your-select-element");
```

Comment: I have another string which is of the same format. I have to loop through the list to find out duplicates from 'options', and then append distinct option values

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
var input  = '<option value="1000133925">Abhishek</option><option value="1000182033">FRESH</option><option value="1000390154">Testing</option>';
var output = {};

$(input).each(function(){
  output[$(this).val()] = $(this).text();
});
```

Output:

```
Object {1000133925: "Abhishek", 1000182033: "FRESH", 1000390154: "Testing"}
```

Comment: +1 because it's usually safer to parse than to regex.

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution :

```
var obj = {}, m, r = /<option value="([^"]*)">([^<]*)<\/option>/g;
while (m = r.exec(s)) obj[m[1]] = m[2];
```

It builds

```
{1000133925: "Abhishek", 1000182033: "FRESH", 1000390154: "Testing"}
```